# How do I get reference the items so I can delete them in a clearinventory command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, quick.db

I'm trying to make a **clearinventory** command so it deletes a players inventory via mention or if there is no mention it deletes your own inventory but I keep getting an error called **RangeError: Too many parameter values were provided** this is the code :

```
const db = require('quick.db');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {

  name: "clearinventory",

  descrition: "clear a players inventory",

  async run(client, message, run) {

    let target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    let items = await db.fetch(target.id, {
      items: []
    });

    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!')

    db.delete(items);

    message.channel.send(`${target}\'s inventory was successfully cleared!`)

  }


}
```

I've tried to specify the items in the variable items and I also tried to specify items in the `db.delete(items, 'car')` but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking at this without any context on which line is causing the issue.

`db.delete` takes a string for the first parameter, this string being the key of the data you set (the target's user ID). In this case, you're passing `items` which is actually an object with the format `{ items: [/* items */] }` and not a string. I assume you're trying to delete the items of a player's inventory, and in that case you can do either of the two:

1. Delete the player's information entirely. You can do that by deleting that entry in the database. If you plan on adding more information to the same entry, I suggest going with the second option instead.

```js
    // target.id is a string, so you can just use that here directly.
    db.delete(target.id);
```

2. Clear the player's inventory (only) by setting `items` to an empty array. This takes advantage of quick.db's ability to use the dot notation.

```js
    // <target.id>.items, e.g. 1234567890987543212.items
    db.set(`${target.id}.items`, []);
```